# Error: Is not a function (java script)

Tags: javascript

I have the follwoing code parts:

```js
 Canvas.prototype.pixelOnMouseOver = function pixelOnMouseOver(callback){
  var canvas = this._canvas;
  var w = this._canvasSize.width, h=this._canvasSize.height;
  var data = this._canvas.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data;
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function(e){
    var idx = (e.offsetY*w + e.offsetX)*4;
    var parts = Array.prototype.slice.call(data,idx,idx+4);
    callback.apply(canvas,parts);
  },false);
```

AND

```js
 var wasOver;
antCanvas.pixelOnMouseOver(function(r,g,b,a){
  var isOver = a > 10; // arbitrary threshold
  if (isOver != wasOver){
    wasOver = isOver;
  }
  
});
```

Now I get the Error that canvas.addEventListener is not a function. How can I fix this problem? Whar is the reason?

regards

EDIT 1:Here is the HTML code:

```html
<div class="fill pad">
 <div style="border:1px solid #ccc" id="aco-canvas"></div>
    <input type="file" id="fileInput">
    <button id="save_personal_points">Save</button>
    <div class="hr vpad"></div>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><b>Debug Info</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none;" class="aco-info">
                <td>Interation: </td><td id="iteration-info"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none;" class="aco-info">
                <td>Best Distance: </td><td id="best-distance"></td>
            </tr>
    <tr style="display:none;" class="position">
                <td>Position Info: </td><td id="position"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="aco-buttons">
                <td colspan="2"><button id="start-search-btn">Start</button> <button id="clear-graph">Clear</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

I only have posted the in my opinion interessting parts. Because it is not allwoed to so much code only....

Comment: this is because of your `this` keyword - `this` in javascript always refers to the element which called the actual function - in your case it refers to the element calling the `pixelOnMouseOver(callback)` - you understand me?

Comment: I think I understand, but how I coukd fix the problem?

Comment: please also post your HTML

Comment: done, see above :)

Comment: hm sorry but i think this is not your complete JS code - can you update it too plz or better make a jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I hve put the whole on https://jsfiddle.net/j40ze6g6/ . I think this would be easier, so you have teh complete overview, and I can nothig forget ^^

Comment: For short: I work with already existing code. My Idea is to make it possible to click on the edges and change there weights...

Comment: are you talking about the edges of the generated figure or the edges of the `#aco-canvas` element?

Comment: the edges of the generated figure

Comment: do you have no ideas?